# Python: printing bottom up

Tags: python, terminal, output

I have a code in python and I need to print 3 results, the first one at the bottom, the third on the top.

The terminal will print in this order:

first
(pause)
second
(pause)
third

I would like to print in this order instead (there will be a pause in between the output):

...third

...second (pause)

first to be printed (then pause)

in order to simulate this I'm using this sequence of print statement:

```
from time import sleep

print '1'
sleep(1)
print '2'
print '1'
sleep(1)
print '3'
print '2'
print '1'
```

This bottom up printing should be only used specifically for this 3 line output and not globally for all the output.
Is that possible? Thank you

UPDATE:
It seems that the only library I can effectively use for modifying the newline order of the terminal is curses.
I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: yes - it is possible - just print your output in reverse order for these results - python doesn't know which result is which anyway, so it doesn't control the order in which you print them - your code does.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably unclear: I need them to appear on the terminal in that position and order.

Comment: see my answer which will make it clear - the point is your program controls the order of output.

Comment: Given your new code - just reverse the order of your print statements.

Comment: I think that probably escape sequences can do it or ,as you said curses, i will give it a try. But reversing it, doesn't work, terminal will print the first line always on the top.

Comment: curses will always be a `better` solution, escape sequences make for very very messy code.

Comment: thank you, I never tried it.

Comment: @ro_orco, my answer prints values as you want them provided the newlines are not a hard requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to "overwrite" the print outputs for every successive run. If newlines are not a hard constraint, you can do something like this:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(3):
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + ','.join([str(a) for a in range(i+1, 0, -1)]))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

This will first print `1`, wait for a second, overwrite the `1` with `2,1`, wait for a second and then overwrite the `2,1` with `3,2,1`, wait for a second and exit.

The interesting portion is the use of the `\r` in the output string - this is the Unix `carriage return` which causes the stdout file pointer in terminals to move to the leftmost position. Now that the pointer is located at the left-most position, we then print the next set of characters in effect overwriting the previous output.

I use `sys.stdout.write` to avoid the implicit newline or space that `print` adds. The `range` is written in this way to generate a reversed list of numbers to print. The flush is needed to force the characters to be flushed to the output.

This only works as long as the output is on a single line - multi-line outputs like in your example will not work with this method. If you must have multi-line outputs, the [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) library is your best bet.

Comment: Unfortunately the newline is an hard constraint. It is a very interesting answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Examples :

```
  results = ["1","2","3"]

  print "\n".join(results)

  1
  2
  3

  print "\n".join(results[::-1])
  3
  2
  1
```

Comment: I'm sorry is not what i'm looking for, I want the line to appear from the bottom and after a short pause on the top. I realized the post was not clear , I edited it. I add some code.

Comment: so you need to use a window manager like curses, or play around with using escape codes (good luck)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Please post any code that you are stuck with so that people can help you faster. You can use [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed), a python built-in to reverse any iterable you are trying to print.

For example:

```
list = ['1', '2', '3']

for item in list:
    print item

# You get
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

Now if you just want to reverse this order of printing you can do something like this:

```
for item in reversed(list):
    print item

# You get
# 3
# 2
# 1
```

Hope this helps.